# duplicates cannot be removed?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
order_id  reference  price
 2         aqzw      221
 3         aqzw      221
 3         awqe      172
 4         arew      121
 5         arew      121
```

**df.drop_duplicates(subset=['reference', 'price'], keep=False)**

not working any workaround for this

Comment: Please don't post images.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://akuiper.com/console/b5idRPdhTFm4. Do you mean `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['reference', 'price'], keep=False)`

Comment: while applying this code duplicated are not removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['reference', 'price'], keep=False , inplace=True)
```